# C code multithreading Pthread

Tags: c, multithreading, unix, pthreads

I'm preparing for a final exam for my Op sys class and I'm having trouble understanding pthreads. In this code,

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <pthread.h>

    void * action( void * arg ) {
        int t = *(int *)arg;
        printf( "THREAD %u: I'm alive %d\n", (unsigned int)pthread_self(), t );
        sleep( t );
        return NULL;
    }

    int main() {

    pthread_t tid[4];
    int i, t;
    for ( i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++ ) {
        t = 1 + i * 3;
        printf( "MAIN: Creating thread for task %d\n", t );
        pthread_create( &tid[i], NULL, action, &t );
    }

    for ( i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++ ) {
        pthread_join( tid[i], NULL );
        printf( "MAIN: Joined child thread %u\n", (unsigned int)tid[i] );
    }

    return 0;
    }
```

for the output:

```
MAIN: Creating thread for task 1
MAIN: Creating thread for task 4
THREAD 1845290752: I'm alive 4
MAIN: Creating thread for task 7
THREAD 1836898048: I'm alive 7
MAIN: Creating thread for task 10
THREAD 1828505344: I'm alive 10
THREAD 1820112640: I'm alive 10
MAIN: Joined child thread 1845290752
MAIN: Joined child thread 1836898048
MAIN: Joined child thread 1828505344
MAIN: Joined child thread 1820112640
```

why doesn't THREAD #: I'm alive 1 print out along with the rest?
How does the flow of execution happen here?

Comment: "*How does the flow of execution happen here?*" most probably in parallel. And all threads read the *same* `t`, which gets overwritten by every iteration around `pthread_create()`. Think twice!

Answer (score 1):

> why doesn't THREAD #: I'm alive 1 print out along with the rest?

Because `t` is *one* location. passed via

```
    pthread_create( &tid[i], NULL, action, &t );
```

By the time the child thread gets to

```
    int t = *(int *)arg;
```

The main thread can change the value of `t` that had its address passed to the child thread.

Hopefully the point of this exercise is to determine just that.